# Intersect two arrays

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, intersection

How can I find the intersecttion between 2 arrays in C#, in a fast way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) extension method on Enumerable. It works on any `IEnumerable<T>` including arrays.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example use of Linq Intersect.

```
// Assign two arrays.
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 4 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };

// Call Intersect extension method.
var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2);

foreach (int value in intersect)
{
    label1.Text += value + "\n";
}
```