# Find the intersection of two lists using multiple search terms

Tags: c#, list, intersection

I have the following objects (shown in JSON format)

```
 UserBatch1{
       User{ name: user1; jobtitle: admin; department: finance; location: building1; extn: 1234}
       User{ name: user2; jobtitle: techie; department: engineering; location: building2; extn: 4321}
       User{ name: user3; jobtitle:boss; department:management: location: building3; extn: 5555}
}
UserBatch2{
       User{ name: user1; jobtitle: admin; department: finance; location: buildlig1 extn: 1234}
       User{ name: user4; jobtitle: techie; department: manufacturing; location: building4; extn: 8888}
       User{ name: user5; jobtitle: admin; department: management; location: building1; extn: 7777}
}
```

The objects are contained in Lists e.g.

```
List<User> UserBatch1;
List<User> UserBatch2;
```

Using C# how do I find the intersection of these lists where, for example, name contains "user" AND jobtitle = "admin".
Another example is where department = finance AND jobtitle = admin AND location = building1.
I've simplified the problem for clarity but each object will have 10 properties and I'll have 10 lists.  Any combination of properties could be used as search criteria.

Comment: .Where(i => i.department == 'finance' && i.jobtitle = 'admin') etc etc

Comment: And maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248433/intersect-two-arrays for intersection.

Comment: .Where did it - thanks Sythnet P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var User = UserBatch1.FirstOfDefault(i => i.department == "finance" && i.jobtitle = "admin");
```