# How do I get my own number to check with the random numbers for bingo

Tags: c#

My bingo game should be very simple you write 10 numbers from 1 - 25 and it should take out 7 random numbers to compare with my own 10 numbers, and in the end I want it to show the result.

I got messed up with `numbers == bingorow`. How to make it check how many right I had? Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int right = 0;
    bool foundNr = false;
    int[] bingorow = new int[11];
    for (int i = 0; i < bingorow.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to C Sharp Bingo!");
            Console.Write("Write down 10 numbers here: ");
            int bingonr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bingorow[i] = bingonr;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please write 10 numbers!");
            continue;
        }

        int[] number = new int[7];
        Random randmNr = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < number.Length; r++)
        {
            number[r] = randmNr.Next(1, 25);
        }

        if (number == bingorow)
        {
            foundNr = true;
        }

        if (foundNr == true)
        {
            right++;
        }
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Your score: {0} of 7", right);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A new SO user that clearly tried to post a question with details and code, and it gets downvoted with no explanatory comments?  How is this going to help him/her post a better question next time?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do note that there's a lot of extraneous code here.  This question really comes down to: How do I find the [intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248433/intersect-two-arrays) of two arrays?

Comment: @sstan I didn't downvote but this question doesn't have much useful detail about what the OP wants. There are 2 close votes already with that reason - I think it's also the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @sstan The help center is full of information about how to post quality questions, what information should be provided when asking a question, etc.  They were even linked to such a page before they were allowed to ask the question, and had to confirm that they read it.  So they already have all of the means necessary to ask a good question at their disposal, and they choose not to.

Comment: @Servy "Chose not to" is probably too strong phrasing - the OP may not realize that this is not a very good question.

Comment: @xxbbcc They were required to say that they read a page describing what good questions look like, so either they read it, and they know why this isn't a good question, or they didn't, and they now know that they need to go back and read it.

Comment: @Servy Not disagreeing. I just think the OP didn't "choose" to post a bad question, it just came out that way. This is certainly a better question than most first posts and it definitely doesn't deserve 5 downvotes. (Not saying that it's a great question.)

Comment: @xxbbcc They choose to not read the directions on how to ask a good question, or they choose not to follow them, even if they didn't post a question they knew was bad. But given that they said things like, "please don't be hard on my codes" and "here is the mess" seems to indicate that they even knew it was a bad question, and were asking it anyway.

Comment: @Servy There are no bad questions only bad answers. You can clearly see on my code and by saying "don't be hard on my codes" that I'm new at this. It's my first post here and I tried to be clear in my question. If you jugde every new user for not typing a perfect question you won't have many users left to help.

Comment: @Unknown There are *absolutely* bad questions.  There are also bad answers.  The fact that you posted a bad question, knew it, and did it anyway, makes it *worse*.  Saying that you know it's a bad question and want us to ignore that fact is completely inappropriate.  You should instead ask a good question in the first place, instead of telling people to ignore the fact that it's a bad question.  That you're new doesn't mean you can't ask a good question, or that it's okay to ask a bad one.  SO has had a high standard for its whole existence, and it's still here.

Comment: @Unknown: There are ***a lot*** of bad questions being posted daily, and it does create a lot frustration.  Your post certainly was not that bad, but it wasn't that great either. (And truth be told, after your last edits, it's actually much much worse, because it looks like you're just asking other people to do the work for you)  I was just thinking that, considering that your post (at first) did show some effort, that a little helpful comment would not have been too much to ask.

Comment: After seeing the response of my bad question i wanted to delete it and not post anything more here till I got the perfect question if I ever get that. But to late so I at least deleted my bad coding. I got the hint about find the intersection of two arrays. And I don't want anyone to do the code for me just give me a hint and I can learn myself.

Comment: Relevant (and hopfully useful) meta discussions: [discussion 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284117/should-i-welcome-newbie-users-with-a-hint-about-how-to-post-good-questions-or-an), [discussion 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive/252910#252910)

Comment: @Unknown You should _most definitely_ restore your code. Your current edit makes the question nothing but "gimme-teh-codez" which will (and should) be heavily downvoted. (I will downvote its current form in about 15 minutes if you don't revert your changes.) You didn't deserve the 5 downvotes earlier but at this point you vandalized the question and made answers useless because of the lost context. Please revert that and don't feel too frustrated - in the future, ask clean questions with clean code and detail.

Comment: @xxbbcc Is it possible to shorten the code to look more understandable?

Comment: @Unknown You can probably remove the empty `Console.Write` calls but the rest is needed for context. Thanks for restoring the question. If you haven't done so, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (and other help pages) - they'll help you ask questions that won't get downvoted in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sloppy answer, but it might help you with your problem.

First, your for loop will run **11** times regardless of whether the try/catch block fails.

```
int[] bingorow = new int[11];
for (int i = 0; i < bingorow.Length; i++)
```

Second, when you "continue" from the catch, you basically print a message and the program continues. I would advise to throw an appropriate exception.

Third, back to the for loop - the program will accept a value and then run all the code. So basically you would guess 1 out of 7 if you are lucky. Then the loop will run again for a second time and you would get another number... etc. This is why I've taken all the code after the catch outside the loop. That way it will iterate a number of times (in this case 7) and get a number from the input on each iteration. After all 7 numbers have been stored, it will carry on with the rest of the code.

Fourth, not sure if you want the numbers to be in the range 1-25 inclusive.

```
number[r] = randmNr.Next(1, 25);
```

This will return numbers in the range 1-24 inclusive as the upper bound of the Next method is exclusive as Mark has stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063276/4453195

Here is a simple solution to your problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int right = 0;
    int[] bingorow = new int[7]; // Correct me if I'm wrong but I think a 7 number bingo should accept 7 numbers as input
    string[] positions = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh" }; // This is not necessary, but makes the flow slightly clearer.

    Console.WriteLine("#########################");
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to C Sharp Bingo!");
    Console.WriteLine("#########################");
    Console.WriteLine("Please provide your 7 numbers in the range from 1 to 25.");

    for (int i = 0; i < bingorow.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your {0} number:", positions[i]);
            int bingonr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bingorow[i] = bingonr;
        }

        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some error message.");
            // Some Exception should be thrown here don't just use "continue".
            continue;
        }
    }

   int[] numbers = new int[7];
   Random randmNr = new Random();
   for (int r = 0; r < numbers.Length; r++)
   {
       // randmNr.Next(1, 26) will return numbers in the range 1-25 inclusive.
       numbers[r] = randmNr.Next(1, 26);
   }

   // Loop through each number from the input (bingorow) array and check if it is contained in the "winning" (numbers) array
   for (int i = 0; i < bingorow.Length; i++)
   {
       if (numbers.Contains(bingorow[i]))
       {
           right++; // Increment counter on each match.
       }
   }

   {
       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine("### Your score: {0} of 7 ###", right);
       Console.Write("Your numbers:");

       // Print the input numbers.
       foreach (int number in bingorow)
       {
           Console.Write(" {0}", number); // Will not be sorted.
       }

       Console.WriteLine();

       Console.Write("Winning numbers:");

       // Print the winning numbers.
       foreach (int number in numbers)
       {
           Console.Write(" {0}", number); // Will not be sorted.
       }

       Console.WriteLine();

       Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just compare two arrays via `arr1 == arr2`. In c#, arrays are references to different objects.

```
int arr1[] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int arr2[] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
if (arr1 == arr2) // Same as arr1.equals(arr2)
    Console.WriteLine("Same");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not same"); //Will print not same.
```

.Net provides many different methods for comparing arrays and list structures. For .NET 4.0 and higher, [Structural Comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.structuralcomparisons(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used. Else a much simpler version would be to use:

```
int arr1[] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int arr2[] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
Console.WriteLine(arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2)); //Done using Linq.
```

Change `number == bingorow` to `number.SequenceEqual(bingorow)` to check if the arrays themselves are equal. If you're looking for the individual elements that are correct, then you'll need to do a nested loop or some form of `for` loop that checks each individual value in the array.

Ex:

```
for( int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) //or whichever array is shorter
    if(arr1[i] == arr2[i])
       //true
    //else false
```